# how can calculate days between two dates in smarty

Tags: php, smarty

In this scenario, I have created a data of an employee. I have taken an array in php and assigned variables and called them into smarty and created a table with the help of php. In this, I want to calculate days between D.O.j and current date. How can I calculate the difference of days between D.O.j and current date. Kindly help me in to this.

PHP Code:

```
<?php
    include_once "../prepengine-header.php";

    $users = array(
        1 => array(
            'id' => '00AC',
            'name' => 'john',
            'address' => 'California',
            'email' => 'JOHn@yAhOO.com',
            'dob' => '1989/10/06',
            'doj' => '2014/12/04'
            ),
        2 => array(
            'id' => '00XV',
            'name' => 'brad',
            'address' => 'Washington',
            'email' => 'bRAd@gmail.com',
            'dob' => '1980/09/23',
            'doj' => '2005/03/10'
           ),
        3 => array(
            'id' => '00UY',
            'name' => 'swati',
            'address' => 'Mutthiganj',
            'email' => 'SWAti@yahoo.com',
            'dob' => '1990/05/04',
            'doj' => '2013/01/02'
            ),
        4 => array(
            'id' => '002VC',
            'name' => 'smith',
            'address' => 'California',
            'email' => 'SMITH@yahoo.com',
            'dob' => '1989/10/22',
            'doj' => '2013/07/15'
            ),
        5 => array(
            'id' => '00RK',
            'name' => 'crystal',
            'address' => 'New York',
            'email' => 'crystal@GMAIL.com',
            'dob' => '1991/05/28',
            'doj' => '2015/01/15'
            ),
        6 => array(
            'id' => '00PC',
            'name' => 'virat',
            'address' => 'Vadodara',
            'email' => 'VIraT@Yahoo.com',
            'dob' => '1989/01/24',
            'doj' => '2013/04/01'
            ),
    );   
    $head[] = "Serial no.";
    $head = array_merge($head, array_keys($users[1]));
    $theme->assign('head',  $head);
    $theme->assign("table", $users);
    echo($theme->fetch('smartart/p_screen5.tpl'));  
?>
```

Smarty Code:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Screen5</title>
    <style>
    table,tr, th, td, thead
    {
        border: 2px solid #333;
    }
    .rwd-table
    {
        width: 74%;
        height: 77%; 
        text-align: center;   
    } 
    .rwd-table {
        margin: 3em 10em;
        min-width: 300px; 
    } 
    th{
        height: 45px;
        color:  #ADFF2F;
    }  
    body {
      padding: 0 3em;
      font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
      color: #444;
      background: #eee;
    }
    .rwd-table {
      background: #34495E;
      color: #fff;
      border-radius: .4em;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
      tr {
        border-color: lighten(#34495E, 10%);
      }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="data_table" name="data_table">
            <table class="rwd-table">
                <thead>
                    <{foreach from = $head key = heading item = file}>
                        <th><{$file|upper}></th>
                    <{/foreach}>    
                </thead>
                <{foreach from = $table key = heading item = file}>
                <tr>
                    <td><{counter}></td>
                    <td><{$file.id}></td>
                    <td><{$file.name|ucfirst}></td>
                    <td><{$file.address}></td>
                    <td><{$file.email}></td>
                    <td><{$file.dob}></td>
                    <td><{$file.doj}></td>
                </tr>
                <{/foreach}>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
   </html>
```

My table look like: https://www.screencast.com/t/IVjk6Fp46Ef

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to ***research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself*** before posting. If you get stuck on something *specific*, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.

Answer (score 1):

what I am understand from your code, the simple solution to get the days between dates is

```
function getDaysBetweenTwoDates($date1,$date2){
 $date1 = date('y-m-d',strtotime($date1));
 $date2 = date('y-m-d',strtotime($date2));
 $now = new DateTime($date1);
 $ago = new DateTime($date2);
 $diff = $now->diff($ago);
 return $diff->days;
}
```

just pass the two dates in this function, like this

```
echo getDaysBetweenTwoDates('2017/08/01','2017/07/08'); //24
echo getDaysBetweenTwoDates('2017-08-01','2016-07-08'); //389
```

[here you can see the running code](https://ideone.com/nw5ulT)

Comment: any idea about the smarty how can i define it in smarty page

Comment: Put the above method outside the loop enclosed within curly braces and call the method within loop by creating a variable and use this variable. Let me know if you face any problem.

Comment: i am not able to print in table

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

PHP Code:

```
<?php
    include_once "../prepengine-header.php";
    $today = time();
    $users = array(
        1 => array(
            'id' => '00AC',
            'name' => 'john',
            'address' => 'California',
            'email' => 'JOHn@yAhOO.com',
            'dob' => '1989/10/06',
            'doj' => '2014/12/04',
            'diff' => floor(($today - strtotime('2014/12/04')) / 86400)
            ),
        2 => array(
            'id' => '00XV',
            'name' => 'brad',
            'address' => 'Washington',
            'email' => 'bRAd@gmail.com',
            'dob' => '1980/09/23',
            'doj' => '2005/03/10',
            'diff' => floor(($today - strtotime('2005/03/10')) / 86400)
           ),
        3 => array(
            'id' => '00UY',
            'name' => 'swati',
            'address' => 'Mutthiganj',
            'email' => 'SWAti@yahoo.com',
            'dob' => '1990/05/04',
            'doj' => '2013/01/02',
            'diff' => floor(($today - strtotime('2013/01/02')) / 86400)
            ),
        4 => array(
            'id' => '002VC',
            'name' => 'smith',
            'address' => 'California',
            'email' => 'SMITH@yahoo.com',
            'dob' => '1989/10/22',
            'doj' => '2013/07/15',
            'diff' => floor(($today - strtotime('2013/07/15')) / 86400)
            ),
        5 => array(
            'id' => '00RK',
            'name' => 'crystal',
            'address' => 'New York',
            'email' => 'crystal@GMAIL.com',
            'dob' => '1991/05/28',
            'doj' => '2015/01/15',
            'diff' => floor(($today - strtotime('2015/01/15')) / 86400)
            ),
        6 => array(
            'id' => '00PC',
            'name' => 'virat',
            'address' => 'Vadodara',
            'email' => 'VIraT@Yahoo.com',
            'dob' => '1989/01/24',
            'doj' => '2013/04/01',
            'diff' => floor(($today - strtotime('2013/04/01')) / 86400)
            ),
    );   
    $head[] = "Serial no.";
    $head = array_merge($head, array_keys($users[1]));
    $theme->assign('head',  $head);
    $theme->assign("table", $users);
    echo($theme->fetch('smartart/p_screen5.tpl'));  
?>
```

and in your Form:

```
<form id="data_table" name="data_table">
            <table class="rwd-table">
                <thead>
                    <{foreach from = $head key = heading item = file}>
                        <th><{$file|upper}></th>
                    <{/foreach}>    
                </thead>
                <{foreach from = $table key = heading item = file}>
                <tr>
                    <td><{counter}></td>
                    <td><{$file.id}></td>
                    <td><{$file.name|ucfirst}></td>
                    <td><{$file.address}></td>
                    <td><{$file.email}></td>
                    <td><{$file.dob}></td>
                    <td><{$file.doj}></td>
                    <td><{$file.diff}></td>
                </tr>
                <{/foreach}>
            </table>
</form>
```

That's it.

Basically what i did is, i just added a new element "diff" in each of the array. and defined a new variable `$today` at top of the Php code.

And in Form I just added a new "td" in the table which contains the code `{$file.diff}`. It will print the difference in your form.

Please give it a try.

Comment: that's great, if it really helps then please accept this as an answer and also do upvote :)

Comment: i am new in sof my repo is below 15 that why i can't upvote.

Comment: can you see my curl problem.

Comment: can you help me on php program my curl program isn't work properly

Comment: Hello @Amrinder Singh are you online. I need your help in php